# How to read lines from .txt file into this bash script?

Tags: sql, bash

I have this bash script which connects to a postgre sql db and performs a query. I would like to be able to read line from a .txt file into the query as parameters. What is the best way to do that? Your assistance is greatly appreciated! I have my example code below however it is not working.

```
#!/bin/sh

query="SELECT ci.NAME_VALUE NAME_VALUE FROM certificate_identity ci WHERE ci.NAME_TYPE = 'dNSName' AND reverse(lower(ci.NAME_VALUE)) LIKE reverse(lower('%.$1'));"

(echo $1; echo $query | \
    psql -t -h crt.sh -p 5432 -U guest certwatch | \
    sed -e 's:^ *::g' -e 's:^*\.::g' -e '/^$/d' | \
    sed -e 's:*.::g';) | sort -u
```

Comment: Share an example of that text file and where the parameters in that file would end up in your query please. I feel like `sed` may be a good option with some tokens in the sql string, but it's impossible to say without some examples of what you are trying to do.

Comment: @JNevill Thanks for your comment. An example of the text file is:

google.com
apple.com
bing.com
Microsoft.com
facebook.com

The text file contains about 20,000 domains I want to pass into the SQL query line by line

Answer (score 1):

Considering that the file has only one sql query per line:

```
while read -r line; do echo "${line}" | "your code to run psql here"; done < file_with_query.sql
```

That means: while read the content of file_with_query.sql line by line, do something with each line.

Comment: Vitorino Thanks for your answer. Do you mean I should put where you say "your code to run psql here" 

query="SELECT ci.NAME_VALUE NAME_VALUE FROM certificate_identity ci WHERE ci.NAME_TYPE = 'dNSName' AND reverse(lower(ci.NAME_VALUE)) LIKE reverse(lower('%.$1'));"

(echo $1; echo $query | \
    psql -t -h crt.sh -p 5432 -U guest certwatch | \
    sed -e 's:^ *::g' -e 's:^*\.::g' -e '/^$/d' | \
    sed -e 's:*.::g';) | sort -u

Comment: just `psql -t -h ... sort -u –`

Comment: Vitorino Thanks again for your help. I want to read a list of domains from a .txt file line by line as parameters to be used by the sql query. How do I add the reading of a .txt file?

Comment: @Joao_Vitorino What goes in the ... part of the statement?

Comment: .. means `psql -t -h crt.sh -p 5432 -U guest certwatch | \
    sed -e 's:^ *::g' -e 's:^*\.::g' -e '/^$/d' | \
    sed -e 's:*.::g';) | sort -u`

Comment: @Joao_Vitorino Thanks for your response. When I try to run that statement I get the error: -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `)'